# How to create DRY HTML?

Tags: html, templates, dry

I have a small static website and every page of this site has a menu and a footer.

What is the best way to make sure changes in the menu and the footer only need to be done in one place and enable me to easily update all my pages which consist of them.

I am looking for some kind of simple template system that enables me to combine files together.

I have looked a bit into ruby .erb files but they seem too complicated for what I want to achieve as I would have to install rails and enable my webserver to use that.

Comment: What technologies *can* you use?

Comment: I have a Debian machine at my disposal. So I can use anything that can be installed there.

Comment: You can try [`Jade`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/). completely client based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple site, there's nothing wrong with doing [server side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html). Simply create the HTML snippets (they don't even have to be fully formed HTML) for your menu and footer. Then on each page, add the appropriate

```
<!-- #include virtual="/footer.html" -->
```

statement in the proper location. Since you're on a Debian server, I'm pretty sure Apache wil already have this enabled by default.

It may seem antiquated, but my wife works for a company that does a lot of maintenance for small websites and they still take this approach and it works just fine.

If your site goes above 10 pages, then I'd say look into some of the templating systems, just to alleviate the need to remember to add your SSI on each new page you create.

Answer (score 3):

you could have a look at some [Web Templating Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system) and decide based on the language/platform you are familiar with

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to combine those on the server side?

For a small static site I simply created a little local script (I used PowerShell, but feel free to use whatever you want or have at your disposal) that does deployment from the local source files which represent the templates. While maybe not as flexible on the template side as full-blown templating engines it's easy, fast and works well for quite a while. Also it runs locally and doesn't need anything except a simple web server on the server side, cutting down on potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: I can combine them on the server side, but I don't really have to. Well writing my own script tends to seem the way to go. I just hoped there would be something to achieve this already.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). It's a static site generator built on top of [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) which uses markdown for content markup and specific template language for constructing pages. So if you only need a site with a few pages you should try jekyll.

It requires for your system to have ruby since all site generation is done on client side and afterwards the site is deployed via rsync.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching the internet for `static site generator`. It gives dozen of solutions in all sort of languages: Python, Ruby, PHP, Haskell, Sh, Bash…

Answer (score 1):

I've used [WML](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/wml) ("Website Meta Language"; NB *nothing* to do with the [WML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Markup_Language) associated with mobile and WAP!) on Debian for years to maintain consistent templated header/sidebar/footer boilerplate for pages on my ISP's static page hosting.